# Is it possible to stake ETH and automatically send the rewards to another wallet?

Tags: ether, smart-contract-wallets, staking

I'm wondering if there is an established way for me to stake ETH from one address and have a different address earn the staking rewards?

Comment: Are you referring to ETH2 staking?

Answer (score 0):

If you are refering to staking on the beacon chain and on the core Ethereum protocol, it should be possible to do it once withdrawal is implemented. This is still being defined and implemented. Withdrawals should be included in the Ethereum protocol in the fork after the one for the Merge.

Comment: More information from Rémy https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/131048/withdrawal-activation-through-a-hard-fork-and-the-role-of-the-eth2-deposit-contr/